# Collection of examples of bad UX design?

Tags: discussion

Would it be ok to open a thread on this site simply asking for "examples of bad UX design"?

I know that such a question doesn't quite fit within the StackExchange guidelines, as it's a bit too open-ended. But I think it could invite a rather interesting collection of answers (and I for one would enjoy submitting a few myself).

Comment: There are Twitter hashes and Tumblr collections that are commonly posted to as well. Maybe not as much discussion there, though.

Comment: If you asked a more specific question like “What are the UX pitfalls in designing ABC with feature XYZ?” that *might* not get closed, but result in answers with specific bad examples.

Answer (score 4):

No. For the reasons you've already stated.

Stack Exchange is a Question and Answer site. Not a discussion forum with threads. You pose a question and people who know how to solve it will give you the answer.

Just because something is about UX, that doesn't mean it fits onto any site that deals with UX.

That stuff is for Yahoo Answers or Quora, not Stack Exchange.